# Как узнать длину пакета по DatagramChannel?

Tags: java, nio2

Вот изучаю [здесь код](http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/practical/JavaSockets2/code/UDPEchoServerSelector.java):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.DatagramChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class UDPEchoServerSelector {
    private static final int TIMEOUT = 3000; // Wait timeout (milliseconds)
    private static final int ECHOMAX = 255; // Maximum size of echo datagram

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        if (args.length != 1) // Test for correct argument list
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter(s): <Port>");
        int servPort = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        // Create a selector to multiplex client connections.
        Selector selector = Selector.open();
        DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open();
        channel.configureBlocking(false);
        channel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(servPort));
        channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ, new ClientRecord());
        while (true) { // Run forever, receiving and echoing datagrams
            // Wait for task or until timeout expires
            if (selector.select(TIMEOUT) == 0) {
                System.out.print(".");
                continue;
            }
            // Get iterator on set of keys with I/O to process
            Iterator<SelectionKey> keyIter = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
            while (keyIter.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = keyIter.next(); // Key is bit mask
                // Client socket channel has pending data?
                if (key.isReadable())
                    handleRead(key);

                // Client socket channel is available for writing and
                // key is valid (i.e., channel not closed).
                if (key.isValid() && key.isWritable())
                    handleWrite(key);

                keyIter.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void handleRead(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
        DatagramChannel channel = (DatagramChannel) key.channel();
        ClientRecord clntRec = (ClientRecord) key.attachment();
        clntRec.buffer.clear();    // Prepare buffer for receiving
        clntRec.clientAddress = channel.receive(clntRec.buffer);
        if (clntRec.clientAddress != null) {  // Did we receive something?
            // Register write with the selector
            key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
        }
    }

    public static void handleWrite(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
        DatagramChannel channel = (DatagramChannel) key.channel();
        ClientRecord clntRec = (ClientRecord) key.attachment();
        clntRec.buffer.flip(); // Prepare buffer for sending
        int bytesSent = channel.send(clntRec.buffer, clntRec.clientAddress);
        if (bytesSent != 0) { // Buffer completely written?
            // No longer interested in writes
            key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
        }
    }

    static class ClientRecord {
        public SocketAddress clientAddress;
        public ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(ECHOMAX);
    }
}
```

И не понимаю, каким образом можно узнать через `DatagramChannel` длину приходящего пакета чтобы из `ByteBuffer` считать нужное количество?

Comment: А что написано в заголовке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прежде всего важно понять, что попадание канала в выборку селектора по готовности на чтение не означает, что пришли **все** данные. Пришло сколько-то данных. Отправляющий код мог передать 512 байт, а селектор может выбрать канал 42 раза - несколько раз по одному байту, несколько раз по нескольку десятков байт и т.д. Поэтому в цикле мультиплексирования нельзя ожидать поступления всех данных, а надо только читать и добавлять в буффер столько, сколько пришло, до тех пор, пока не накопится нужное количество. В тех случаях, когда обмен идёт по tcp и через одно соединение будет передан только один блок данных, проще всего определить об окончании передачи по тому, что метод `read` вернул -1. Если же через один канал передаётся множество блоков или используется udp, то принимающая сторона должна знать, сколько она должна принять. Самый простой, но весьма неудобный способ - это передавать блоки данных фиксированного размера. Другой - это сначала передать `int` или `long`, содержащий размер передаваемых данных, а потом передать столько данных.

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле, оказывается все просто.
Через DatagramChannel делается следующим образом:

```
SocketAddress client = channel.receive(buffer);
buffer.flip();
                        ArrayList <Byte> ab = new ArrayList <>();

                        while (buffer.hasRemaining())
                        {
                            byte b =buffer.get();
                            ab.add(b);
                        }

                        outDataForEncoder = new byte[ab.size()];
                        for(int i=0; i<ab.size();i++)// so not to put primitives
                        {
                            outDataForEncoder [i]=ab.get(i);

                        } buffer.clear();
```

длина списка ab и есть длина данных.

Но это неудобно.  Проще делать через обычный DatagramPacket

```
byte buffer [] = new byte[1200];

         DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
                    udpSocketIn.receive(p);
                    byte  bBuffer [] = p.getData();

                    byte outDataForEncoder [] = new byte[p.getLength()];

                    for(int i =0;i<outDataForEncoder.length;i++)
                    {
                        outDataForEncoder[i]=bBuffer[i];

                    }
```

Суть в том, что делаем сначала размер буфера заведомо больше размера пакета (у меня допустим он не превышает килобайта). В итоге мы имеем байтовый массив заполненный данными и частично до конца нулями. Как же нам отличить нули данных от заполняющих нулей???
Очень просто - методом p.getLength(). Он возвращает размер именно ДОСТОВЕРНЫХ данных без учета оставшихся нулей в буфере.